# Table Cell not selectable after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, autosize

I have a view which should have a different layout in portrait and Landscape mode. I implement a method to redraw my UI elements with Autosizing (no AutoLayout):

```
-(void)buildViewElements:(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait) {
    NSLog(@"Portrait");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        CGRect newImageFrame = CGRectMake(20, 15, 100, 100);
        _personImage.frame   = newImageFrame;
        CGRect newNameLabelFrame = CGRectMake(128, 20, 172, 21);
        _nameLabel.frame = newNameLabelFrame;
        CGRect newNameDescFrame = CGRectMake(128, 41, 172, 21);
        _nameDescriptionLabel.frame = newNameDescFrame;
        CGRect newBorrowedFrame = CGRectMake(128, 64, 75, 21);
        _borrowedLabel.frame = newBorrowedFrame;
        CGRect newBorrowedValueFrame = CGRectMake(211, 64, 42, 21);
        _borrowedValueLabel.frame = newBorrowedValueFrame;
        CGRect newLendFrame = CGRectMake(128, 93, 75, 21);
        _lendLabel.frame = newLendFrame;
        CGRect newLendValueFrame = CGRectMake(211, 93, 42, 21);
        _lendValueLabel.frame = newLendValueFrame;

        CGRect newcontainerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, [CNX_Tools getLargestAttributeOfSize:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size] - 194);
        _tableContainerView.frame = newcontainerFrame;
        CGRect newDetailFrame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 29);
        _detailSelector.frame = newDetailFrame;
        CGRect newTableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 36, 320, newcontainerFrame.size.height - 39);
        _tableView.frame = newTableFrame;
    }];
}
else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape) {
    NSLog(@"Landscape");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        CGFloat factor = 1.0f;
        CGFloat diff   = 0.0f;
        if ([CNX_Tools getLargestAttributeOfSize:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size] <= 480) {
            // iPhone4 size
            factor =  0.8f;
            diff   = 10.0f;
        }

        CGRect newImageFrame = CGRectMake(75*factor-diff, 20, 100, 100);
        _personImage.frame = newImageFrame;
        NSLog(@"Bild Frame %f", newImageFrame.origin.x);
        CGRect newNameLabelFrame = CGRectMake(20, 140, 210*factor, 21);
        _nameLabel.frame = newNameLabelFrame;
        CGRect newNameDescFrame = CGRectMake(20, 161, 210*factor, 21);
        _nameDescriptionLabel.frame = newNameDescFrame;
        CGRect newBorrowedFrame = CGRectMake(20, 184, 75, 21);
        _borrowedLabel.frame = newBorrowedFrame;
        CGRect newBorrowedValueFrame = CGRectMake(103, 184, 42, 21);
        _borrowedValueLabel.frame = newBorrowedValueFrame;
        CGRect newLendFrame = CGRectMake(20, 213, 75, 21);
        _lendLabel.frame = newLendFrame;
        CGRect newLendValueFrame = CGRectMake(103, 213, 42, 21);
        _lendValueLabel.frame = newLendValueFrame;

        CGRect newContainerFrame = CGRectMake(250*factor, 0, [CNX_Tools getLargestAttributeOfSize:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size] - 250*factor, 268);
        _tableContainerView.frame = newContainerFrame;
        CGRect newDetailFrame = CGRectMake(20, 10, newContainerFrame.size.width - 40 , 29);
        _detailSelector.frame = newDetailFrame;
        CGRect newTableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 49, newContainerFrame.size.width, 219);
        _tableView.frame = newTableFrame;
    }];
}
```

}

This method is called from method:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        [self buildViewElements:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait duration:duration];
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        [self buildViewElements:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait duration:duration];
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        [self buildViewElements:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape duration:duration];
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        [self buildViewElements:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape duration:duration];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

The method getLargestAttributeOfSize: returns the largest size attribute (height or width).

If I start the view in portrait I can tapp an the table cells and method tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is called. After a rotation to landscape mode all cells are not selectable and I cannot scroll in the table. But, if I leaf this screen and call ist again (in landscape mode), the same table cells are selectable, the method is called and I can stroll trough the table. If I rotate the device to portrait, I have the same faulty behavior. After a rotation of my device I can not interact with my table and its cells.

Can someone help me please or have an idea what's my issue here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that a superview of your `UITableView` is not adjusted correctly. The input can than never reach your `UITableView`, but when it is started fresh all is well. Probably the view of your `UIViewController`.

Try setting `clipsToBounds:YES` to the superviews to see if your `tableView` is actually out of the views bounds.

Comment: If I set this flag to my super view _tableContainerView the table is not visible anymore. So I assume that there is a problem with my containerView. Now I'm looking for the reason but I can not find anything. I compared the bounces and frames of my container and table view but it looks like as expected.

Comment: Can you post a sample project with all those views and some dummy data?

Comment: OK, I found my issue - Autosizing masks. The method willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: is executing before the device is rotating. So all elements are at the right position. Now the device rotates and my autosizing mask changes the elements for the new situation. Unfortunately my container view is very small. Thanks for the answers!